# How to change Search Display Template for Person Result Type

Tags: search-results, display-template

I am trying to add a link to the Hover Panel of the People Item Display Template.  I've can't change the Display Template for the Person Result Type.  It seems you can't edit Result Types provided by the Search Service.

I can copy the Person Result Type, and make my changes, but how will the Search Result know to use my Result Type and not the default one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create copy of Person Result Type(target is your new People Item Display Template)

Create copy of  People Item Display Template and apply changes.

Follow this articles
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-change-the-way-search-results-are-displayed

Comment: And if you are customizing search display templates often, I can really recommend having a look at VS code, Search query tool, Google dev tools and the VS code add on SPGo 